# Keeping remote repository in sync through a rebase

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I have a situation where I will have to rebase a topic branch to a master. That's fine, it's the normal rebase case and works great.

The complication is when I'm trying to get this process to be in sync on a bare remote repository.

e.g.

```
o--o--o origin/master
       \
        o--o origin/topic

o--o--o clone/master - tracking origin/master
       \
        o--o clone/topic - tracking origin/topic
```

Now I make a commit to clone/master which I push to origin/master, so far so good.

```
o--o--o--n origin/master
       \
        o--o origin/topic

o--o--o--n clone/master - tracking origin/master
       \
        o--o clone/topic - tracking origin/topic
```

This is where I want to end up:

```
o--o--o--n origin/master
          \
           o--o origin/topic

o--o--o--n clone/master - tracking origin/master
          \
           o--o clone/topic - tracking origin/topic
```

I just can't seem to get there, please help.

The workflow is:

1. Clone the bare remote origin

   Make changes to clone/master

   Push changes to origin/master

   Rebase clone/topic to either origin or clone master - doesn't seem to make too much difference

   Now I want the origin/topic to reflect the rebase so I want to push but first I have to pull to make clone/topic fast forward then I end up a merge which has all the original commits from clone/topic with all the commits from origin/topic on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would modify slightly workflow that you have in order to avoid push --mirror.

1. git clone /path/to/origin # clones the master
2. git checkout --track origin/topic
3. git checkout master
4. git add some_new_file; git commit -m "added some new file"
5. git push origin/master
6. git checkout topic #Local branch
7. git rebase master
8. git push origin master #it will update master on origin
9. git push --force origin/topic : it will update topic on origin

You need --force because origin/topic will change the ancestor and you have disable fast forward check.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the answer is to push with the --mirror flag. So now the workflow is:

1. git clone /path/to/origin # clones the master

   git checkout --track origin/topic

   git checkout master

   git add some_new_file; git commit -m "added some new file"

   git push origin/master

   git checkout topic #Local branch

   git rebase master

   git push --mirror origin #This is the step I had wrong, just a regular push is not good enough

Also note that I'm not sharing the remote repo with anyone but myself otherwise rebasing wouldn't be fair to the other developers.